# Loop across columns

Tags: excel, vba

I understand how to loop down a row, but how do you loop across columns. So for example, I want to go from

```
.Range("AA2:AA") to ("AB2:AB") to ("AC2:AC")
```

without having to copy and paste my code and change manually

Thanks!

Comment: `.Range("AA2:AA")` etc., aren't actual ranges, but they assumedly consist of more than one cell. A little more if on what cells/ranges your loop would cycle through would be helpful.

Comment: I'd like to refer to define this as a range with column numbers so that i can loop through  varCharter = .Range("A2:A" & Lastrow) so instead of "A2:A" I could use .column(). i guess i need to use R1C1 on this?